# A proof of Minkowski's ramification theorem without the use of geometry of numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification, geometry-of-numbers

Consider the following theorem due to Minkowski (originally conjectured by Kronecker iirc):

> For any proper finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb Q$, some prime in $\mathbb Q$ ramifies in $K$. Equivalently, the discriminant of $K$ has absolute value greater than $1$.

The proof of this result is a well-known consequence of Minkowski's convex body theorem, and indeed this was how he has originally proven this result. I was wondering whether, after all these years, a significantly different proof has been devised. More precisely, is there a proof of this theorem which avoids the use of geometry of numbers? If not, can we possibly prove that there are only finitely many unramified extensions (a special case of [Hermite-Minkowski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem))?

I'd like to point out [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19021/avoiding-minkowskis-theorem-in-algebraic-number-theory) which is closely related, but doesn't address this specific theorem. As answers there point out that Minkowski's convex body theorem is, in a way, a sharpening of pigeonhole principle, so I can imagine that some clever application of this theorem might be able to provide us with a proof of some bound on the discriminant strong enough to give the desired result.

Comment: We need to show that $|d_K|>1$ for the absolute discriminant. Minkowski gives $|d_K|\ge\frac{\pi}{3}(\frac{3\pi}{4})^{n-1}>1$; perhaps this can be achieved by a "strengthening" of the pigeon principle, as Felipe says.

Answer (score 4):

Landau has given an arithmetic proof in *Der Minkowskische Satz über die Körperdiskriminante* (Minkowski's Theorem on the field discriminant) 
Gött. Nachr. 1922, 80-82, where he replaced Minkowski's geometry of number by Dirichlet's pigeonhole principle. Here's an English [translation](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/landau.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The Stark-Odlyzko discriminant bounds give a purely analytic proof of Minkowski's theorem, using the functional equation of $\zeta_K(s)$. See this paper:

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tmj/1178240652

As in Minkowski, the basic point is to show that $|\Delta_K| > 1$.
The paper above doesn't give the explicit bounds in low degree necessary to conclude this for all degrees, but for that one can see:

www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/unpublished/discr.bound.tables.pdf

(gives a sufficiently good bound for $[K:\mathbf{Q}] \ge 8$)

www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/unpublished/discr.bound.table2

(gives sufficiently good bounds for degrees $2$ to $8$.)

${}{}{}$