# Why is the discriminant of number fields greater 1?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, discriminant

Is there an immediate proof not using Minkowski's bound that we have $|\Delta_K|>1$ for all number fields $K \ne \mathbb Q$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034826/a-proof-of-minkowskis-ramification-theorem-without-the-use-of-geometry-of-numbe

Answer (score 3):

There is a proof by E. Landau in 1922 using the pigeonhole principle.

There is [an English translation.](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/landau.pdf)

Comment: The link seems to be offline by now.